# Pandas Left Outer Join results in table larger than left table

Tags: python, pandas

From what I understand about a left outer join, the resulting table should never have more rows than the left table...Please let me know if this is wrong...

My left table is 192572 rows and 8 columns.

My right table is 42160 rows and 5 columns.

My Left table has a field called 'id' which matches with a column in my right table called 'key'.

Therefore I merge them as such:

```
combined = pd.merge(a,b,how='left',left_on='id',right_on='key')
```

But then the combined shape is 236569.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Can you post some minimal data the demonstrates this (not all 200k please)?

Comment: @PaulH the problem is that I can't find the reason it's doing this...when I use this `pd.merge` on a small section of the code the resulting table is indeed only the size of the left table

Comment: You can get an unexpected number of rows if you merge on keys having Nans.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You can expect this to increase if keys match more than one row in the other DataFrame:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [2, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [1, 6]], columns=['A', 'C'])

In [13]: df.merge(df2, how='left')  # merges on columns A
Out[13]: 
   A  B   C
0  1  3   5
1  1  3   6
2  2  4 NaN
```

To avoid this behaviour [drop the duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) in df2:

```
In [21]: df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['A'])  # you can use take_last=True
Out[21]: 
   A  C
0  1  5

In [22]: df.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['A']), how='left')
Out[22]: 
   A  B   C
0  1  3   5
1  2  4 NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to suppress that? In your example, I don't need to see line 0 or 1, only to see one of the 2 lines...

Comment: @Chowza yup, drop the duplicates, edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: Just realised, that if you do this for an _inner_ join rather than a left one, you need to remove the duplicates in **both** dataframes as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580295/4288043) answer.

Comment: In my case, the keys were also matching on more than one row in the other dataframe, as Andy Hayden said, so I ended up with much more rows than wanted. But, when using the "drop_duplicates()" solution I lost many of the matches that wanted to be there (i.e. the observations were present in my left and right dataframe). The solution that worked for me was to merge on two keys, which created a match for just on one row AND gave me all the matches I needed. For an example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277473/merge-two-dataframes-based-on-multiple-keys-in-pandas

Answer (score 15):

A small addition on the given answers is that there is a parameter named validate which can be used to throw an error if there are duplicated IDs matched in the right table:

```
combined = pd.merge(a,b,how='left',left_on='id',right_on='key', validate = 'm:1')
```

Answer (score 12):

There are also strategies you can use to avoid this behavior that don't involve losing the duplicated data if, for example, not all columns are duplicated. If you have

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [2, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [2]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [1, 6]], columns=['A', 'C'])
```

One way would be to take the mean of the duplicate (can also take the sum, etc...)

```
In [3]: df3 = df2.groupby('A').mean().reset_index()

In [4]: df3
Out[4]: 
     C
A     
1  5.5

In [5]: merged = pd.merge(df,df3,on=['A'], how='outer')

In [6]: merged
Out[204]: 
   A  B    C
0  1  3  5.5
1  2  4  NaN
```

Alternatively, if you have non-numeric data that cannot be converted using pd.to_numeric() or if you simply do not want to take the mean, you can alter the merging variable by enumerating the duplicates. However, this strategy would apply when the duplicates exist in both datasets (which would cause the same problematic behavior and is also a common problem):

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 3], ['b', 4],['b',0]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [8]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 3], ['b', 8],['b',5]], columns=['A', 'C'])

In [9]: df['count'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].cumcount()

In [10]: df['A'] = np.where(df['count']>0,df['A']+df['count'].astype(str),df['A'].astype(str))

In[11]: df
Out[11]: 
    A  B  count
0   a  3      0
1   b  4      0
2  b1  0      1
```

Do the same for df2, drop the count variables in df and df2 and merge on 'A':

```
In [16]: merged
Out[16]: 
    A  B  C
0   a  3  3        
1   b  4  8        
2  b1  0  5
```

A couple of notes. In this last case I use .cumcount() instead of .duplicated because it could be the case that you have more than one duplicate for a given observation. Also, I use .astype(str) to convert the count values to strings because I use the np.where() command, but using pd.concat() or something else might allow for different applications.

Finally, if it is the case that only one dataset has the duplicates but you still want to keep them then you can use the first half of the latter strategy  to differentiate the duplicates in the resulting merge.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple entries with same key value(s). Make sure there is no duplicates with respect to key in right table.

```
# One workaround could be remove duplicates from right table w.r.t key.

combined = pd.merge(a.reset_index(),b.drop_duplicates(['key']),how='left',left_on='id',right_on='key')
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this , create a Unique INDEX column in the LEFT DataFrame, so you can track this "INDEX" column for "Duplicates" after you have the "Merged Dataframe" ready.

```
 1. LEFT_df['INDEX'] = LEFT_df.index + 1
 2. LEFT_df.shape 
 3. Merged_df = pd.merge(LEFT_df , Right_df , how = "left", on = 'Common column')
 4. LEFT_df['INDEX'].duplicated().sum()
 5. Merged_df = Merged_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['INDEX'], keep='first')
 6. Merged_df.shape (will now match with the LEFT_df.shape)
```

Answer (score -2):

use drop_duplicates
in your case will be:

```
merged = pd.merge(df,df3,on=['A'], how='outer').drop_duplicates()
```