# Merge two DataFrames based on multiple keys in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

For example, I have two tables (DataFrames):

`a`:

```
A  B  value1
1  1      23
1  2      34
2  1    2342
2  2     333
```

and `b`:

```
A  B  value2
1  1    0.10
1  2    0.20
2  1    0.13
2  2    0.33
```

The desired result is:

```
A  B  value1  value2
1  1      23    0.10
1  2      34    0.20
2  1    2342    0.13
2  2     333    0.33
```

Does pandas have any functions to support merge (or join) two tables based on multiple keys?

Answer (score 111):

To merge by multiple keys, you just need to pass the keys in a list to [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
>>> pd.merge(a, b, on=['A', 'B'])
   A  B  value1  value2
0  1  1      23    0.10
1  1  2      34    0.20
2  2  1    2342    0.13
3  2  2     333    0.33
```

In fact, the default for `pd.merge` is to use the intersection of the two DataFrames' column labels, so `pd.merge(a, b)` would work equally well in this case.

Answer (score 11):

According to the most recent pandas documentation, the on parameter accepts either a `label` or `list` on the field name and must be found in both data frames. Here is an MWE for its use:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':['0', '0', '1','1'],'B':['0', '1', '0','1'], 'v':True, False, False, True]})

b = pd.DataFrame({'A':['0', '0', '1','1'], 'B':['0', '1', '0','1'],'v':[False, True, True, True]})

result = pd.merge(a, b, on=['A','B'], how='inner', suffixes=['_and', '_or'])
>>> result
    A   B   v_and   v_or

0   0   0   True    False
1   0   1   False   True
2   1   0   False   True
3   1   1   True    True
```

> on : label or list
> Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both DataFrames. If on is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

Check out latest [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) documentation for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `left_on=`, `right_on=`, `left_index=` or `right_index=` parameters as well. The values are matched in the order the keys are passed in that case; the first key in `left_on` will be matched with the first key in `right_on` etc.

So using the example in the OP, the following two produce the same output:

```py
a.merge(b, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['A', 'B'])
a.merge(b, on=['A', 'B'])
```

However, `a.merge(b, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['B', 'A'])` will produce a very different output because `a['A']` is matched to `b['B']` and `a['B']` is matched to `b['A']`.

This is especially useful if the keys to match are named differently. For example:

```py
a.merge(b, left_on=['A1', 'A2'], right_on=['B1', 'B2'])
```

This is equivalent to the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.A1=b.B1 AND a.A2=b.B2
```

---

A useful note: Because reindexing occurs under the hood ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2ef7eb322cb86e0df36141b4b9391e385bbdde69/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py#L879)), the merged output is sorted by the values in the left keys (apparently that's not the case in cudf 24.02 but that's another matter).