# Intersection on two keys python panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv file say one.csv and two.csv. Format of file is One.csv:

```
ID1 , att 1 , att 2
a1    b1      c1
a2    b2      c2
a3    b3      c3
```

for two.csv

```
ID2, att1, att2
E1    b6    c9
E2    b2    c2
E3    b1    c1
E4    b1    c3
```

I need create a new csv file three .csv where only the entries with same att1 and att2 value should be present

```
ID1 ,   ID2,   att1 ,  att2
a1       E3      b1      c1
a2       E2      b2      c2
```

How can i achieve this in python using panda?
I've gone through [Merge two DataFrames based on multiple keys in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277473/merge-two-dataframes-based-on-multiple-keys-in-pandas). But in my case the length of both the data frames is different.

Comment: Did you try a merge?

Comment: length is not equal error

Comment: I want to see your code, then.

Comment: @jezrael as att1 and att2 are same for both of them

Comment: I need both att1 and att2 to be same not just att1 @jezrael

Comment: Sorry, `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['att1', 'att2'])`

Comment: @jezrael this gives a not in index error . KeyError: "['A' 'C'] not in index"

Comment: @user3767047 - then use `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['a', 'b'], right_on=['c', 'd'])` - join for columns a, b in df1 with c,d columns in df2

Comment: @jezrael i still get the error len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)

Comment: so there is not same length of columns in `left_on` and `right_on` 
?