# pandas: merged (inner join) data frame has more rows than the original ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python 3.4 on Jupyter Notebook, trying to merge two data frame like below:

```
df_A.shape
(204479, 2)

df_B.shape
(178, 3)

new_df = pd.merge(df_A, df_B,  how='inner', on='my_icon_number')
new_df.shape
(266788, 4)
```

I thought the `new_df` merged above should have few rows than `df_A` since merge is like an inner join. But why `new_df` here actually has more rows than `df_A`?

Here is what I actually want:

my `df_A` is like:

```
 id           my_icon_number
-----------------------------
 A1             123             
 B1             234
 C1             123
 D1             235
 E1             235
 F1             400
```

and my `df_B` is like:

```
my_icon_number    color      size
-------------------------------------
  123              blue      small
  234              red       large 
  235              yellow    medium
```

Then I want `new_df` to be:

```
 id           my_icon_number     color       size
--------------------------------------------------
 A1             123              blue        small
 B1             234              red         large
 C1             123              blue        small
 D1             235              yellow      medium
 E1             235              yellow      medium
```

I don't really want to remove duplicates of my_icon_number in df_A. Any idea what I missed here?

Comment: you have duplicate `my_icon_number` in both datasets.

Comment: @piRSquared: Would you please elaborate a little more? Thanks!

Comment: Your simple illustration is not representative of actual. Likely, you have repeat *my_icon_number* in `df_B`. Where you think it's a one-to-many join between `b` and `a`, it's actually many-to-many, hence the more records returned.

Comment: You can get an unexpected number of rows if you merge on keys having Nans.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because you have duplicates of the merge column in both data sets, you'll get `k * m` rows with that merge column value, where `k` is the number of rows with that value in data set 1 and `m` is the number of rows with that value in data set 2.

try `drop_duplicates`

```
dfa = df_A.drop_duplicates(subset=['my_icon_number'])
dfb = df_B.drop_duplicates(subset=['my_icon_number'])

new_df = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, how='inner', on='my_icon_number')
```

---

## Example

In this example, the only value in common is `4` but I have it 3 times in each data set.  That means I should get 9 total rows in the resulting merge, one for every combination.

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame(dict(my_icon_number=[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], other_column1=range(6)))
df_B = pd.DataFrame(dict(my_icon_number=[4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7], other_column2=range(6)))

pd.merge(df_A, df_B,  how='inner', on='my_icon_number')

   my_icon_number  other_column1  other_column2
0               4              3              0
1               4              3              1
2               4              3              2
3               4              4              0
4               4              4              1
5               4              4              2
6               4              5              0
7               4              5              1
8               4              5              2
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an example above to illustrate what I actually need. Am I doing wrong by using inner join here? Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame then you're fine.  You just need to be comfortable with the fact that your results may end up with more rows than you thought because of representing all combinations.

Comment: Thanks, I was starting to question my sanity before I saw this

Comment: Is this thread alive? I'm afraid I still don't understand this.