# Pandas merge returning more results than either original dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have used a python script to create a pair of very long single column DataFrames each corresponding to all invoices for a given item over a given timeframe.

The goal is to merge these dfs into a third df in such a way that only the invoice numbers that appear in both original dfs make it into the third. The reason, if it helps, is to study how often the items are purchased together.

I found a few posts where duplicate values in one/both dfs can cause the merge to create more rows than intended and I checked both using df.drop_duplicates() but since both were filled from a SELECT DISTINCT query there are no duplicates on either list.

I have tried specifying the key and not specifying the key for the merge function, but since I only have one column I'm not sure what else to try adjusting. There is something about the merge function that I'm not understanding.

For reference,

```
df1.shape
(5176423, 1)
df2.shape
(2837968, 1)

df3 = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2)
(36692320, 1)
```

Comment: It looks like you're running into the issue outline in [pandas: merged (inner join) data frame has more rows than the original ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41580249/15497888) it's not clear without samples of your DataFrames why this behaviour is occurring. You do not specify any columns for the merge which means it will attempt to merge on the intersection of all columns which may be at issue if there are duplicates in the shared columns.

Comment: I have tried merging on 'INVOICE' which is the column name in question and the result is the same. I found that despite dropping duplicates from both dfs prior to merging the resultant df after merge contained many duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'indicator' to see how they're merging?

```
df3 = pd.merge(left = df1, right = df2, indicator = True)
```

```
df3["_merge"].value_counts()
```

Knowing the source of each row may help you.

Also, I've not merged that way - I would use:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = '*key*', indicator = True)
```

As the default type for a join is “inner”, the resulting data set will only contain observations included in both input data sets.

Comment: When using the indicator and viewing the results it is showing that all 36 million results were in both of the original dfs. Also, it looks like the second method you recommended returns the same result.

Comment: After further investigating it looks like running a drop_duplicates on df3 drops the size from (36692320, 1) to (400110, 1) which is a viable number. So at this point I'm just not sure why so many duplicates were introduced in the first place.