# Merge two dataframes with different time ranges by repeating values within time range, group and ID, in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two distinct dataframes as Pandas Dataframes, both with a time information column, with different time intervals. The first df1 has time intervals in seconds (~6s) and the other (df2) has time intervals of 1min. I would like to merge both dataframes, keeping the information from both df, repeating df2 values within the time range, sensorid and date in df1. Like this:

**df1**

```
sensorid    time               date     x   y   z
1   2023-08-04T06:00:00.000 2020-07-31  32  11  22
1   2023-08-04T06:00:06.000 2020-07-31  41  42  21
1   2023-08-04T06:00:12.000 2020-07-31  22  22  44
23  2023-08-04T08:20:00.000 2020-08-02  21  56  45
23  2023-08-04T08:20:06.000 2020-08-02  45  53  12
23  2023-08-04T08:20:12.000 2020-08-02  12  31  51
```

**df2**

```
sensorid    time    date    behavior    animal  position
1   06:00   31/07/2020         3          22       1
23  08:20   02/08/2020         1          44       2
```

**merged_df**

```
sensorid    time                date    x   y   z   behaviour   animal  position
1   2023-08-04T06:00:00.000 31/07/2020  32  11  22         3      22      1
1   2023-08-04T06:00:06.000 31/07/2020  41  42  21         3      22      1
1   2023-08-04T06:00:12.000 31/07/2020  22  22  44         3      22      1
23  2023-08-04T08:20:00.000 02/08/2020  21  56  45         1      44      2
23  2023-08-04T08:20:06.000 02/08/2020  45  53  12         1      44      2
23  2023-08-04T08:20:12.000 02/08/2020  12  31  51         1      44      2
```

Whereas when transforming the time column into time_date for Pandas, the dates were wrong, as it was the date on which the column was converted and not the actual date to be considered, which is in the date column.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prepare the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''sensorid    time               date     x   y   z
1   2023-08-04T06:00:00.000 2020-07-31  32  11  22
1   2023-08-04T06:00:06.000 2020-07-31  41  42  21
1   2023-08-04T06:00:12.000 2020-07-31  22  22  44
23  2023-08-04T08:20:00.000 2020-08-02  21  56  45
23  2023-08-04T08:20:06.000 2020-08-02  45  53  12
23  2023-08-04T08:20:12.000 2020-08-02  12  31  51'''

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

data = '''sensorid    time    date    behavior    animal  position
1   06:00   31/07/2020         3          22       1
23  08:20   02/08/2020         1          44       2'''

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Next, make sure the `"date"` columns are of the same datetime type in both frames:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], dayfirst=False)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Finally, merge them on the columns of interest, having previously discarded the column with time from the second table:

```
df1.merge(df2.drop('time', axis=1), on=['sensorid','date'])
```

*p.s. You may be interested in reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580295/14909621) on the question about increasing number of rows after inner join*

---

`pandas: 1.5.1`

Comment: As I am completing df1, repeating information that is in df2, shouldn't I have a df_merged with the same amount of rows in df1? Because my df1 contains 1,279,305 rows, df2 has 17,304 rows, but df_merged has 375,646,088 rows.

Comment: @RafaelNakamura You may have several records in `df2` with the same `sensorid` and `date` but maybe different `time` and other fields. All of them are connecting with corresponding `sensorid` and `data` in `df1` therefore making the result bigger.