# Pandas DataFrame merge, ends up with more rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, left-join

I am doing

```
a_df = a_df.merge(b_df, how='left', on=['col1', col2])
```

After this, `a_df` actually has more rows than before the operation. How is this possible?

They both have millions of rows, so it's hard for me to narrow down the problem. Probably I am missing something about how left merge works.

Comment: please post a sample data with less no of records and expected output

Comment: The dataframes have millions of rows, I can't possibly upload them here.

Comment: put a sample of 5 rows in two df and its expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Left Outer Join results in table larger than left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720739/pandas-left-outer-join-results-in-table-larger-than-left-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with duplicates, so instead left join `merge` return all combination of dupplicates pairs of both `DataFrame`s, check sample below:

```
a_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'col1':[5,5,5,9,9,9],
                   'col2':list('aaabbb')})

print (a_df)
   A  B  C  D  col1 col2
0  a  4  7  1     5    a
1  b  5  8  3     5    a
2  c  4  9  5     5    a
3  d  5  4  7     9    b
4  e  5  2  1     9    b
5  f  4  3  0     9    b

b_df = pd.DataFrame({'E':[7,8,0,1],
                     'F':list('efgh'),
                     'col1':[5,5,9,9],
                     'col2':list('aabb')})

print (b_df)
   E  F  col1 col2
0  7  e     5    a
1  8  f     5    a
2  0  g     9    b
3  1  h     9    b
```

---

```
a_df = a_df.merge(b_df, how='left', on=['col1', 'col2'])
print (a_df)
    A  B  C  D  col1 col2  E  F
0   a  4  7  1     5    a  7  e
1   a  4  7  1     5    a  8  f
2   b  5  8  3     5    a  7  e
3   b  5  8  3     5    a  8  f
4   c  4  9  5     5    a  7  e
5   c  4  9  5     5    a  8  f
6   d  5  4  7     9    b  0  g
7   d  5  4  7     9    b  1  h
8   e  5  2  1     9    b  0  g
9   e  5  2  1     9    b  1  h
10  f  4  3  0     9    b  0  g
11  f  4  3  0     9    b  1  h
```

---

**Solution1** is remove duplicates in second `DataFrame`:

```
b_df = b_df.drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2'])
print (b_df)
   E  F  col1 col2
0  7  e     5    a
2  0  g     9    b

a_df = a_df.merge(b_df, how='left', on=['col1', 'col2'])
print (a_df)
   A  B  C  D  col1 col2  E  F
0  a  4  7  1     5    a  7  e
1  b  5  8  3     5    a  7  e
2  c  4  9  5     5    a  7  e
3  d  5  4  7     9    b  0  g
4  e  5  2  1     9    b  0  g
5  f  4  3  0     9    b  0  g
```

**Solution2** is create unique values of pairs `col1` and `col2` by aggregation:

```
b_df = b_df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index=False).agg({'E':'mean', 'F': ','.join})
print (b_df)
   col1 col2    E    F
0     5    a  7.5  e,f
1     9    b  0.5  g,h

a_df = a_df.merge(b_df, how='left', on=['col1', 'col2'])
print (a_df)
   A  B  C  D  col1 col2    E    F
0  a  4  7  1     5    a  7.5  e,f
1  b  5  8  3     5    a  7.5  e,f
2  c  4  9  5     5    a  7.5  e,f
3  d  5  4  7     9    b  0.5  g,h
4  e  5  2  1     9    b  0.5  g,h
5  f  4  3  0     9    b  0.5  g,h
```

Also is possible check all dupes in `df_b` by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (b_df[b_df.duplicated(['col1', 'col2'], keep=False)])

   E  F  col1 col2
0  7  e     5    a
1  8  f     5    a
2  0  g     9    b
3  1  h     9    b
```