# Trying to do a left join of two datasets but getting strange results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To make this as clear as possible I started with a simple example. I created two random dataframes

```
dummy_data1 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
        'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
dummy_data2 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '6', '7', '8'],
        'Feature3': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'],
        'Feature4': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['id', 'Feature3', 'Feature4'])
```

And if I apply this `df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'id', how='outer')` or `df_merge = df1.merge(df2,how='left', left_on='id', right_on='id')` I get the desired output of

[image]

Now I am trying to apply the same technique with two large datasets that have the same number of rows. All I want to do is join the columns together into one large dataframe. The length of each dataframe is `512573` But when I apply

```
df_merge = orig_data_updated.merge(demographic_data1,how='left', left_on='Location+Type', right_on='Location+Type')
```

Then the length magically becomes `3596301` which is simply not possible. My question is simple. How do I do a left join on two dataframes such that the number of rows is the same and I just join the columns together?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Left Outer Join results in table larger than left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720739/pandas-left-outer-join-results-in-table-larger-than-left-table)

Comment: What is happening here is cartesian product caused by multiple records in either or both dataframes with same key.

Comment: do a groupby key and count then filter the results by those with count greater than 1,  if your count is great then 1 then you we get a multiplying of records.

Comment: @ScottBoston Could you provide an answer please?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Sorry, I don't have an answer for your problem.  This is just a suggestion on what I think is causing your issues.

Comment: @M_S_N The link provided answers my question. Thank you!