# pandas.merge result is larger than the two separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have to dataframes `a, b` with datetimeindices and want to merge them, so that all indices are included and where holes occur, nan-values will be.

this worked in the past:

```
df = pd.merge(train_t1s.iloc[:lols],       sym_train_t1.iloc[:lols],      how='outer', sort=True, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but suddenly It creates a dataframes which ist a lot longer than `a` & `b` together (e.g. `a`'s length is 2000 and `b`'s length is 2000 too, but `df`'s length will be 316000000)

`a` and `b` each own only one column. this column consists also of datetimevalues in the same format (so maybe this could be the cause)

a:

```
                                  col_a
2019-07-22 18:18:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:19:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:20:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:21:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:22:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:23:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:24:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:25:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:26:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:27:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:28:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:29:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:30:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:31:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:32:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:33:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:34:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:35:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:36:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:37:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:38:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:39:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:40:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:41:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:42:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:43:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:44:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
```

b

```
                                  col_b
2019-07-22 17:40:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:41:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:42:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:43:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:44:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:45:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:46:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:47:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:48:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:49:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:50:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:51:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:52:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:53:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:54:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:55:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:56:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:57:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:58:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 17:59:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:00:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:01:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:02:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:03:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:04:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:05:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
2019-07-22 18:06:00 2019-07-23 15:54:00
```

Here is a sample of "what I think" my data would look like:

```
import pandas as pd 
periods_A = 102; periods_B = 57;
ix1= pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start="2019-07-21 09:25:00", periods=periods_A, freq="T")) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["2019-07-21 09:25:00"]*len(ix1)}, index=ix1)  
ix2=pd.date_range(start="2019-07-20 22:25:00", periods=periods_B, freq="T") 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B":["2019-07-20 22:25:00"]*len(ix2)}, index=ix2)  
result = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer', sort=True, left_index=True, right_index=True)  
print(len(df1), len(df2), len(result))
```

Am I missing something out here?

Why pd.concat doesnt work:

```
import pandas as pd
periods_A = 20; periods_B =20;
ix1= pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start="2019-07-21 09:25:00", periods=periods_A, freq="T"))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["2019-07-21 09:25:00"]*len(ix1)}, index=ix1)

ix2=pd.date_range(start="2019-07-21 09:23:00", periods=periods_B, freq="T")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B":["2019-07-21 22:29:00"]*len(ix2)}, index=ix2)

result1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer', sort=True, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(len(df1), len(df2), len(result1))
#print(df1, df2)
print(result1)

result2 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(len(df1), len(df2), len(result2))
print(result2.sort_index())
print(result1.equals(result2.sort_index()))

# output:
# pd.merge:
20 20 22
                                       A                    B
2019-07-21 09:23:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:24:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:26:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:27:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:28:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:29:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:30:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:31:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:32:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:33:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:34:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:35:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:36:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:37:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:38:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:39:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:40:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:41:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:42:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:43:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:44:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
20 20 40


#pd.concat
                                       A                    B
2019-07-21 09:23:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:24:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:25:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:26:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:26:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:27:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:27:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:28:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:28:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:29:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:29:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:30:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:30:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:31:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:31:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:32:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:32:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:33:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:33:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:34:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:34:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:35:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:35:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:36:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:36:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:37:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:37:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:38:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:38:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:39:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:39:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:40:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:40:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:41:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:41:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:42:00                  NaN  2019-07-21 22:29:00
2019-07-21 09:42:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:43:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
2019-07-21 09:44:00  2019-07-21 09:25:00                  NaN
False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Left Outer Join results in table larger than left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720739/pandas-left-outer-join-results-in-table-larger-than-left-table)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222131/discussion-between-la-li-lu-le-low-and-trenton-mckinney).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This answer is a commination of the following:

  - [Pandas Left Outer Join results in table larger than left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720739/)
  - [Remove rows with duplicate indices (Pandas DataFrame and TimeSeries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764)
- Please review the following:

  - [pandas User Guide: Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)
  - [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/)
- The end analysis of the files is, there are 563 non-unique indices, which are associated with 563 non-unique column values, therefore these 563 duplicate indices from both dataframes can be removed.
- Once the duplicate data is removed, the dataframes can be joined to produce the expected output.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read files, convert to datetime and set as index
df1 = pd.read_csv('a_.csv', parse_dates=[0, 1], index_col=[0])
df2 = pd.read_csv('b_.csv', parse_dates=[0, 1], index_col=[0])

print(len(df1), len(df2))
[out]:
3519 3519

# check the number of unique values in the index
df1.index.nunique()
df2.index.nunique()

[out]:
2956
2956
```

- Both files have 563 non-unique index values, which will merge into `563**2` rows

### Review the duplicate values

```
# see only the duplicated index and associate column data
dup1 = df1[df1.index.duplicated()]
dup2 = df2[df2.index.duplicated()]

# check if the column values are unique
dup1.nunique()
dup2.nunique()

[out]:
b_col    1
dtype: int64
a_col    1
dtype: int64
```

- Of the values associated with the duplicate indices, there is 1 unique value in the columns, which means all the column values are the same.

### Remove duplicates and join

- drop the duplicated indices with [`pandas.Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```py
df1 = df1[~df1.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
df2 = df2[~df2.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

# join the dataframe

result = df1.join(df2, how='outer', sort=True)

print(len(df1), len(df2), len(result))
print(result.shape)
[out]:
2956 2956 2956
(2956, 2)
```