# pd.merge question. how=left creates more observations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
print(len(df))
264764
```

```
df = df.merge(df2[['id','Re']], on=['id'], suffixes=('', '_fwd1'), how='left')
print(len(df))
2714684
```

why would this result in more data than df originally had? Even when i do how='inner' which should be the intersection of keys i get more observations.

Comment: The keys in `df` likely match multiple rows in `df2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Left Outer Join results in table larger than left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720739/pandas-left-outer-join-results-in-table-larger-than-left-table)

Comment: I'll take a look, id's should have been unique but your answer makes sense